# I run `docker rm <container id>` command to delete my containers, but why is the image gone as well?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-image

I run a docker container from an image. Then I want to delete the container by `docker rm <containerID>` and restart it again. But I found the image is deleted as well!! But I didn't run the `docker rmi <image>` command at all. Why it is deleted automatically? I have to pull the image again and again to restart my container. Although I can use `docker stop` command to just stop a container so not to pull the same image again and again, but the question I posted is still wired, isn't it? Is there any one can help me, thanks!

Comment: The command `docker rm` only removes the container and not the image. What command did you do to start the container?

Comment: I want to stop and remove the unused containers: 1. docker stop $(docker ps -aq); 2 docker rm $(docker ps -aq)   These two commands should not cause the image being deleted in common, right ?

Comment: Are you sure that your container is gone? Did you try `docker container ls --all`?

Comment: I just tried as you told, and the output is empty.

Comment: How did you start the container in the first place? What command did you use?

Comment: I started the container by docker-compose from yaml. I thought it was because of my docker-compose version is out of date. But when I run a demo container by `docker pull training/webapp`, `docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py;` and remove it as well ,the same thing just happend . By the way , my Docker Version: `18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`, Thanks

Comment: The command `docker container ls` with the  `--all` flag should show you all the container in your system. Without the flag, only the running ones are showing.

Comment: emm.. The command `docker ps -a` has the same effect with that. But my question is still exists

Comment: Do you mean that `docker images` does not show your image anymore after you removed your container with `docker rm <imageName>` ? This is not supposed to happen. If this is the case, there is something specific in your environment that you have to find out.

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out the problem by `docker info`. It shows that my two paras `Deferred Removal Enabled` and `Deferred Deletion Enabled` are all set *false*. The introduction of these two paras [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

My problem solved by:

```
$ sudo dockerd --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=false --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=false
```